# Get transistent/scoped Database access in singletonservice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

i updating my app from asp core 1.0 to 2.0. In 1.0 i have a soulution for my longlive import-task, initialated as singleton. The singleton used the DBContext. But in core 2.0 this soulution dosn't work. Can you help me?

My soulution in aps core 1.0 was

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnection")));
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IDataStore, DataStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IImportRepository, ImportRepository>();
```

with

```
public class ImportRepository : IImportRepository
{

    Importer Importer;

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext DBContext;
    private readonly IDataStore store;
    private ImportSet runningSet = null;

    public ImportRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataStore store)
    {
        this.DBContext = context;
        this.store = store;
        Importer = new Importer(DBContext, store);
    }
```

With this soulutions i get errormessages (in german, but i try to translate). "you cannot use scoped services in singleton"

Last attempt i used this solution

```
services.AddSingleton<ImportService>(
                provider => new ImportService((ApplicationDbContext)provider.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)))
                );
```

But here i get the errormessage "Cannot resolve scoped service 'Portal.Data.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider."

How can i get access to my database in my Import-Service?

Answer (score 1):

You may resolve dependencies manually using `IServiceProvider` instance.

```
public class ImportRepository : IImportRepository
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public ImportRepository(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        ...
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var dBContext = (ApplicationDbContext) provider.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
        ...
    }
}
```

---

By the way, there is an extension method `GetService<T>();`  defined in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace:

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
var dBContext = provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your singleton lives longer and is shared, the only option I see is that you take it as a parameter to the functions.

```
public class ImportRepository : IImportRepository
{
    public void DoSomething(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataStore store)
    {
    }
}
```

The other option is to make `ImportRepository` scoped as well.

Comment: I have already tried this, but the ImportRepository used a list of tasks. the tasks worked as list one after one. I need the access inside the task. if i your solution, dosomething is already done, if the next task start to work. but I experiment again with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have a soulution, that works, but not perfektly.

Like Juunas example i build a long life funktion

```
    public async Task RunImportAsync(string fileName, DataService data)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(internalPath + fileName))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Datei {fileName} nicht gefunden.");
            }
            [long Operations...]
            data.DBContext.Add(new ImportHistory(set));
            data.DBContext.SaveChanges();
        });
    }
```

the call is simple

```
          [HttpPost]
    [Route("runImport")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunImport([FromBody]dynamic body)
    {

        string id = ""; 
        try
        {
            id = body.filename;
            _logger.LogInformation($"Import from {id}");
            await ImportService.RunImportAsync(id, DB);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Success_2xx.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return SendError(e);
        }


    }
```

But postmen get no Response with this solution. Is there a idea, how i can fix it?